# How to globally speed up ViewController transition animations in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

`ViewController.present(vc, animated: true)` and segues in navigation controllers.

How can I somehow speed these animations up, preferably globally?

Comment: tl;dr `window.layer.speed = 2.0` in your AppDelegate or use a custom transition.